# Set a Default Value for an Option?

Tags: options

Does Wordpress have a way to set a default value for an option?

That is -- I know `get_option` accepts a second parameter, and will return that parameter if no value is set.  For example, when I'm setting up my form to let users save a value, I might use something like this

```
<td>
    <input type="text" 
           name="new_option_name" 
           value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name','default') ); ?>" 
    />
</td>
```

If `new_option_name` doesn't have a saved value, `get_option` will return `default`.

**However** -- when I fetch the value in other places (i.e. I want to **use** the value), I need to specify the string again.  This introduces the possibility of mistakes

```
$someOtherVariable = get_option('new_option_name','defaultt');
```

Other settings systems I've worked with give you the ability to configure a default value for settings that have not yet been saved.  Does Wordpress have a feature like this?  Or is it up to the end user programmers to make sure their `get_option` defaults match in all their code?

Comment: Sorry, nothing out of the box. What about a decorator function for `get_option`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything clever that I can see.  I've used two approaches in the past:

1 - Your plugin's activation code could save all your default options, so that you never need to use the second parameter to `get_option`  Really, this equates to your...

> default value for setting that have not yet been saved.

2 - You could define a set of constants for the default values, and then use those constants for the second parameter to `get_option`